# No value has been specified for property ERROR

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following code snippet in my build.gradle , and error occurs displaying the user and password property is not set , however as you can see i get this variable by `System.getenv()`

```
cargo {
  containerId = 'tomcat7x'
  port = 8080

  deployable {
    context = 'ROOT'
    file = file("build/libs/${rootProject.name}-${version}.war")
  }

  remote {
    hostname = 'myhostname.com'
    username = System.getenv('TOMCAT_USER')
    password = System.getenv('TOMCAT_APASSWORD')
  }
}
```

Error message when execute task with depends of this configuration:

```
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':cargoDeployRemote'.
> No value has been specified for property 'username'.
> No value has been specified for property 'password'.
```

Comment: Are you sure that TOMCAT_USER and TOMCAT_APASSWORD [sic] are defined? What if you print out those values from a simple task/

Comment: Certainly and print the correct values.